# Dual fulfillments

Tags: prophecy, messiah

Can anyone provide examples of prophecy that has dual fulfillment?
That which has happened will happen again.

However, there is a distinction between a story that has happened paralleling to a prophecy yet to happen, (like Judges7:25 and Isa10:26).

I'm more looking for prophecy foretelling an event that occurs and yet will occur again.

Like Acts 2:16 and Joel 2:28-32 which is yet to happen but has happened in Acts 2.

Answer (score 0):

Isaiah prophesied in 2:

> 19
> People will flee to caves in the **rocks** and to **holes** in the ground from the fearful presence of the LORD and the splendor of his majesty, when he rises to shake the earth.

Hosea echoed it in 10:

> 8
> The high places of wickedness will be destroyed— it is the sin of Israel. Thorns and thistles will grow up and cover their altars. Then they will say to the **mountains**, “Cover us!” and to the **hills**, “Fall on us!”

Jesus was on his way to be crucified in
Luke 23:

> 26As the soldiers led him away, they seized Simon from Cyrene, who was on his way in from the country, and put the cross on him and made him carry it behind Jesus. 27A large number of people followed him, including women who mourned and wailed for him. 28Jesus turned and said to them, “Daughters of Jerusalem, do not weep for me; weep for yourselves and for your children. 29For the time will come when you will say, ‘Blessed are the childless women, the wombs that never bore and the breasts that never nursed!’ 30Then
>
> “ ‘they will say to the **mountains**, “Fall on us!”
> and to the hills, “Cover us!” ’
>
> 31 For if people do these things when the tree is green, what will happen when it is dry?”

This was first fulfilled when Rome laid siege on Jerusalem.

Gill explains:

> and their miseries being inexpressible, and intolerable, they will seek to go into the **holes** of the rocks, and **caves** of the earth, as is prophesied of them, Isaiah 2:19 and as **Josephus** says, many of them did, when the city was taken; and, like those in Hosea 10:8 will say, "to the mountains fall on us, and to the hills cover us"; will choose rather that the mountains and hills round about Jerusalem, should fall upon them, and they be buried under the ruins of them, than live in such terrible distress, or fall into the hands of their enemies!

Pulpit elaborates:

> Verse 30. - Then shall they begin to say to the mountains, Fall on us; and to the hills, Cover us. The allusion, in the **first** place, was to the awful siege of **Jerusalem** and to the undreamed-of woes which would accompany it; and in the **second** place, to the centuries of misery and **persecution** to which the children of these "daughters of Jerusalem" would, as Jews, be subjected in all lands.

Still, there is a future fulfillment describes in
Revelation 6:

> 15
> Then the kings of the earth, the princes, the generals, the rich, the mighty, and everyone else, both slave and free, hid in **caves** and among the **rocks** of the mountains.

Comment: Thank you Tony I like that

Comment: +1 Glad to be of service. Don't let Close(2) discourage you. It happens to me too as recently as only a few days ago :) I try to learn from the closings.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few prophecies that have a dual fulfillment:

1. Matt 24:3 - While Jesus was sitting on the Mount of Olives, the disciples came to Him privately. “Tell us,” they said, “when will (a) these things happen, and (b) what will be the sign of Your coming and of the end of the age?”  Thus, Jesus combined the destruction of Jerusalem with the end of the world when He would return
2. Isa 7:14 - *Therefore the Lord Himself will give you a sign: Behold, the virgin will be with child and will give birth to a son, and will call Him Immanuel*.  This was a prophecy about Isaiah's wife but was also applied to Mary and Jesus as per Matt 1:23
3. Joel 2:28-32 is an example of a prophecy that was fulfilled at Pentecost in Acts 2 but which appears to be capable of fulfillment again in the period before Jesus returns
4. Hos 10:8 about the wicked asking to be destroyed by rocks and mountains is a prophecy about the destruction of Jerusalem; but it also receives a dual application by Rev 6:15-17 at the end of time when Jesus returns.
5. The prophecy about Gog and Magog in Eze 38 concerns the punishment meted out to these pagan nations in OT times.  However, it given a second impetus in Rev 20:8 in the time after the 1000 years.

Note that in all of these cases (this is not an exhaustive list), the second application can only be claimed where such is explicit in the bible text itself and NOT simply due to the over-active imagination of the exegete.

Comment: Thank you Dottard I like those answers